# Get a list of blobs in azure container using SSIS

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-blob-storage

I am working on an SSIS project. I am an amateur.

I have the pictures for my products in an Azure container. I want to get a list of the filenames i.e 001.jpg that exist in a container and export them in Excel.

I have managed to connect to my Azure storage but I do not know what task to use to get this list.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Hi,If my answer is helpful for you, you can vote it or accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

SSIS only support two tasks about Azure Blob Storage:

1. [Azure Blob Download Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/azure-blob-download-task?view=sql-server-2017)
2. [Azure Blob Upload Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/azure-blob-upload-task?view=sql-server-2017).

We also can reference this document  [Azure Blob Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/azure-blob-source?view=sql-server-2017) in SSIS.

For example, download all files in the BlobContainer "containerleon" from Blob:
[image]

[image]

There is no task can help you get a list of the filenames i.e 001.jpg that exist in a container and export them in Excel in SSIS.

Hope this helps.